# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '_1' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Trying to run this query I wrote to return a list of files in a course, but running into this error that a conversion failed when converting the varchar value '_1' to data type int.

```
SELECT cm.course_id, cc.title title, cc.dtmodified dtmodified, MIN(xf.FILE_SIZE) file_size, MIN(crl.resource_id) resource_id, MIN(xu.FULL_PATH) full_path
  FROM BBLEARN.dbo.cms_resource_link crl
  INNER JOIN BBLEARN.dbo.course_contents cc ON cc.pk1 = crl.parent_pk1
  INNER JOIN BBLEARN.dbo.course_main cm ON cm.pk1 = crl.crsmain_pk1
  INNER JOIN BBLEARN.dbo.course_users cu ON cm.pk1 = cu.crsmain_pk1
  INNER JOIN BBLEARN.dbo.users u ON cu.users_pk1 = u.pk1
  INNER JOIN BBLEARN_CMS_DOC.dbo.XYF_FILES xf ON crl.resource_id = xf.ENTRY_ID + '_1'
  INNER JOIN BBLEARN_CMS_DOC.dbo.XYF_URLS xu ON xu.FILE_ID = xf.FILE_ID
  INNER JOIN BBLEARN_CMS_DOC.dbo.XYF_FILES xf2 ON xu.PARENT_ID = xf2.FILE_ID
  WHERE crl.parent_data_type='content'
  AND cu.role='P'
  AND crl.storage_type='PUBLIC'
  AND xf.FILE_TYPE_CODE='F'
  AND (LOWER(xu.FILE_NAME) LIKE N'%.mov%' or LOWER(xu.FILE_NAME) LIKE N'%.avi%' or LOWER(xu.FILE_NAME) LIKE N'%.wm%' or LOWER(xu.FILE_NAME) LIKE N'%.mp%' or LOWER(xu.FILE_NAME) LIKE N'%.rm%' or LOWER(xu.FILE_NAME) LIKE N'%.flv%' or LOWER(xu.FILE_NAME) LIKE N'%.amr%' or LOWER(xu.FILE_NAME) LIKE N'%.aif%' or LOWER(xu.FILE_NAME) LIKE N'%.aup%' or LOWER(xu.FILE_NAME) LIKE N'%.m4%' or LOWER(xu.FILE_NAME) LIKE N'%.wav%' or LOWER(xu.FILE_NAME) LIKE N'%.swf%')
  AND xu.FULL_PATH NOT LIKE '/internal/%'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM BBLEARN.dbo.cms_resource_link
                WHERE crsmain_pk1 = crl.crsmain_pk1
                AND parent_pk1 = crl.parent_pk1
                AND parent_data_type='content'
                AND resource_id = xf2.ENTRY_ID + '_1' )
  GROUP BY cm.course_id, cc.pk1, cc.title, cc.dtmodified ORDER BY 1;
```

Which shows up in line 7 and 21 I believe where there is the concatenation of `xf.ENTRY_ID + '_1'` and `xf2.ENTRY_ID + '_1'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `xf2.ENTRY_ID` is an `INT`, SQL will not try to concatenate the values, but add them together. You need to explicitly cast the `INT` to a `VARCHAR`, or `CHAR` in order to concatenate them.

Change

```
AND resource_id = xf2.ENTRY_ID + '_1'
```

To

```
AND resource_id = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),xf2.ENTRY_ID) + '_1'
```

And

```
INNER JOIN BBLEARN_CMS_DOC.dbo.XYF_FILES xf ON crl.resource_id = xf.ENTRY_ID + '_1'
```

To

```
INNER JOIN BBLEARN_CMS_DOC.dbo.XYF_FILES xf ON crl.resource_id = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),xf.ENTRY_ID) + '_1'
```

I am defining a `VARCHAR(20)` as `ENTRY_ID` could be of `BIGINT` data type (though i think you should have way too much rows in order to need 20 digit long ids...

Comment: [Please, please, please specify a length for VARCHAR](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I wouldn't know the right length for this case, that is why i omitted it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't even know for sure if it is a `TIMYINT`, `SMALLINT`, `INT` or `BIGINT`...So, what would be the best for the case?

Comment: I usually use `VARCHAR(12)` for `INT` but if it might be `BIGINT` then 20 should be safe.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I read your article, which is good by the way, but i don't think it would really matter in this case. When Declaring columns or variables, sure it does, but here it would take as much as it would need in each execution, meaning each row???? Wouldn't it?

Comment: "This case" is not the issue, it's about promoting best practices ***always***, and no, it still would not "take as much as it would need." If you had some data type > 30 characters and convert to varchar without a length, it would truncate at 30. Try it: `SELECT TOP (10) name, CONVERT(VARCHAR, name)
FROM sys.all_objects WHERE LEN(name) > 30;`

Comment: @AaronBertrand hmmm...Interesting. I really didn't know that. It seems that it never occurred to me as i never use it without the length in variables and columns. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

try this.You should cast xf.ENTRY_ID and xf2.ENTRY_ID in varchar type with appropirate range right now im using Max length for the same. Hope your code will work.

Like this:

```
cast(xf.ENTRY_ID varchar(max)) + '_1' and cast(xf2.ENTRY_ID as varchar(max)) + '_1'
```